# Jquery: Unable to find div element in a jquery $(data)

Tags: jquery

I have `$(data)` whose output is (its a big array so i am showing the screenshot

[image]

I am trying to select the div using id `container` but its not selecting

```
$(data).find('div#container')
```

Why its not working? also the screenshot is as below
[image]

Where as if i try to select another div as shown below snapshot

[image]

```
$(data).find('div.container-wrap')
```

it shows the div, the screenshot as below
[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery `find()` or plain javascript `find()` method here?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put $. It jquery. edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is used to find descendants of the set of elements, what you want is [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set of matched elements as what you're looking for is at the top level.

```
jQuery(temp0).filter('div#container');
```

Comment: Then how come `$(temp0).find('div.container-wrap')` is working

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi as stated in the answer, `find` looks for descendants of selected elements, `div.container-wrap` is a descendant of `div#container` hence it was found.

Comment: Then how to get the `<body>` and `<html>` tag in this case with `$(data)`